# Django how to save objects in a for loop from list

Tags: python, django, for-loop, model

I want to save x MediaStreams for one Media Object. So I have a One-to-Many relation here (ForeignKey) but I'm not sure how I can this working as currently always the same stream gets saved and not 5 different ones as expected. Where do I need to place "i" to make this working for object creation within the for-loop?

```
for i in clean_result['streams']:
    new_stream = MediaStreams.objects.create(index=index_value, stream_bitrate=streambitrate_value,
                                               codec_name=codec_name_value, codec_type=codec_type_value,
                                               width=width_value, height=height_value,
                                               channel_layout=channel_layout_value, language=language_value,
                                               media=new_object)
    new_stream.save()
```

Currently only and every time index 5 gets saved and not 0-5 - clean_result['streams']['index'].

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the stack trace please?

Comment: @DeanElliott Sorry but now I dont have this issue anymore, so no stacktrace ... Still I'm not able to loop trough a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned your solution, since you are calling `objects.create()` you do not need to call `save()`. Also since you are expecting the values inside `clean_result['streams']` to exist you can do the following:

```
for i in clean_result['streams']:
    MediaStreams.objects.create(
        index=i['index'],
        stream_bitrate=i['bit_rate'],
        codec_name=i['codec_name'],
        codec_type=i['codec_type'],
        width=i['width'],
        height=i['height'],
        channel_layout=i['channel_layout'],
        language=i['tags']['language'],
        media=new_object
    )
```

If there is a chance the values don't exist, you can use `i.get('index')` which returns `none` if the `index` does not exist. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey) for `dict.get()` explaination on StackOverflow.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#create) for the Django docs on for `objects.create()` which calls the save also.

Comment: One question, all this seems to work fine except for ['tags']['language'] If i want to use i.get this always fails with:

’’’language=i.get['tags']('language'),
celery           | TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable’’’

And yes the chance that the field is empty is pratically always given

Comment: okay, got it working: language=i.get("tags", {'x': None}).get("language")

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through dict items.

```
dict_ = {'color': 'blue', 'fruit': 'apple', 'pet': 'dog'}
>>> for item in dict_.items():
...     print(item)
...
# output will be like this:
('color', 'blue')
('fruit', 'apple')
('pet', 'dog')
```

In your case:

```
for i in clean_result['streams'].items():
    # do your stuff
```

If you want to know more about how to iterate through a dictionary in python check out this [link](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/).

Comment: with this snipped I get : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: i thought you are working with a `dict` as the title of your question says. it means you object is a `list` not a `dict`. you can iterate through a list like `for i in your_list` and it should be fine and if you still have problem it's from somewhere else.

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly, my bad.